# refactor to ARC gives error implicit error [picture]

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I am refactoring to use ARC in my project and can not figure out this problem for the life of me!

I don't know where I got the code from.

[screenshot of error http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/972/xcode.png](http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/972/xcode.png)"screenshot of error"
http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/972/xcode.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not using bridged casting. You have to use bridging to cast between C types and Objective-C types:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"earthquake" context:(__bridge void *)itemView];
```

When casting from a C pointer type to an Objective-C type:

```
UIView * item = (__bridge UIView *)context;
```

Comment: Just to note, there are more than just __bridge, there is also __bridge_retained and __bridge_transfer. You need to be aware of which one to use in which situations.